# How to retrieve data from Real Time Database(Firebase) of anonymous path

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a path in Real Time Database ("sports") inside which data would be set using setValue under a child name which is declared by the user. How do I get the String from the database.
Example-: User writes a string in EditText named userWrite, then-:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("sports");
mDatabase.setValue.child(userWrite).setValue("Socks");
```

As the string to be retrieved has to already be defined in "Strings.class" using *ignoreExtraProperties*, How will I retrieve the data when I can't declare it in a Strings.class file as the String will be provided by the user? (which is necessary for my project's algorithm to work)

**Update**-:
Number of times the user can create a userWrite and add it to the database is not limited, so I need a method which will allow me to directly search for a certain String either without declaring it in Strings.class, which I doubt is possible or I need a method in which I can declare the String in another Activity and use the get method using 
      
`String check=AnotherClass.userWrite`

Data Tree-:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- sports
         |
         --- pushID
            |
            ---userWrite
               |
                ---pushID-UserWrittenText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you can change this line of code:

```
mDatabase.setValue.child(userWrite).setValue("Socks");
```

to

```
mDatabase.child("userWrite").setValue(userWrite);
```

Assuming that the user has written in the `EditText` the String `Socks`, your database structure will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- sports
         |
         --- userWrite: "Socks"
```

Now to get the value of the `userWrite` property which is `Socks`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userWriteRef = rootRef.child("sports").child("userWrite");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String userWrite = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", userWrite);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userWriteRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

According to your comment, I recommend you to create a map and use `push()` method like this:

```
mDatabase.child("userWrites").push().setValue(userWrite);
```

In this case, your database structure will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- sports
         |
         --- userWrites
               |
               --- pushedIdOne: "Socks"
               |
               --- pushedIdTwo: "Another Pair of Socks"
               |
               --- //and so on
```

To get the values of all those new created properties, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userWritesRef = rootRef.child("sports").child("userWrites");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userWrite = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", userWrite);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userWritesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the number of userwrites are infinite, there might be 1, or a 100, so to check each one I can't name them under the same child as they may overwrite

Comment: And what should I declare in my Strings.class file?

Comment: No, there is no need for that because you are setting the String value directly on the reference. Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: My Data Tree looks like this, sports-->PUSHid-->"userWrite"--> PushID(newID) -->userWrittenString ...As it is different from I have mentioned your answer is not working, It may be because of my data being slightly different as I mentioned, could you just check as why It won't work with it?...Not working= The Log.d does not send any information

Comment: You shoul use this line of code: `mDatabase.child("userWrites").push().setValue(userWrite);` to add, as already mentioned in my answer. So will have sports->userWrites->pushedId->userWrittenString. So in your case you are missing a child. I gave you this database structure because your with yours is not possible to achive that. The reason is that you are missing a child. Please see the second database structure.

Comment: I cannot change the writing data part as if a user writes the same String twice it will overwrite the previously written data so It is necessary for me to keep the userWrite under the pushID, so my Data writing part looks like this-:
    `mDatabase.push().child("userWrite").push().setValue(userWrittenString);`

Comment: You should change it otherwise you cannot achieve this. Using this database strcucture you'll also be able to check for duplicates.

Comment: It would be great If you could just help me with one more thing, If I want to categorize the Log.d with, Log.d("TAG", userWrite+":"+positionOfTheItem);
How do I find out the position?

Comment: Add all item to a list while looping and then use: Log.d("TAG", userWrite+":"+list.indexOf(userWrite));